# How do I set the animation speed? (pygame, python)

Tags: python, pygame

```
keystate = pg.key.get_pressed()
        if keystate[pg.K_LEFT]:
            self.counter = (self.counter + 1) % len(player_images)
            self.acc.x = -PLAYER_ACC
            self.image = pg.transform.flip(player_images[self.counter], True, False)
            self.image.set_colorkey(WHITE)
```

Here is my code. How do I make it so that the walking animation of the player will slow without changing the FPS? I would like an example.

Comment: That's an exact duplicate of your last question which also seems to be a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a variable called `slowdown`, for example, and then add it to your line, from this:

```
self.image = pg.transform.flip(player_images[self.counter], True, False)
```

To this:

```
self.image = pg.transform.flip(player_images[self.counter / slowdown], True, False)
```

That makes it so that if you do `slowdown=2`, for example, the animation will be half as fast.

Make sure your `self.counter` is an int, or add a floor function to `self.counter/slowdown`. I think you don't need this though.